# c# :The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, wcf-binding, ntlm

I was trying to create an adapter service (Web API calling a WCF service). I have gone through a ton of questions with the similar titles and can't seem to solve the problem. Can anyone please help.

Is there something that I am missing apart from configuring the web.config.

I added a service reference and updated the web.config as below

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpEndpoint">
          <security mode="Transport" >
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
           </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://service.com/service-Hosted-somewhere-else.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpoint"
        contract="Service" name="BasicHttpEndpoint">
      </endpoint>    
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Stack-trace as below

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAAEAAQADgAAAAFgpmiGd2ol9pcGzEAAAAAAAAAAN4A3gBIAAAABgGxHQAAAA9JAE4AVABFAFIATgBBAEwAAgAQAEkATgBUAEUAUgBOAEEATAABAB4AUgBTAEsAUAAtAE0ARQBMAC0ATwBQAFQAOABFAFYABAAqAGkAbgB0AGUAcgBuAGEAbAAuAHMAdQBuAGcAYQByAGQALgBjAG8AcgBwAAMASgBSAFMASwBQAC0ATQBFAEwALQBPAFAAVAA4AEUAVgAuAGkAbgB0AGUAcgBuAGEAbAAuAHMAdQBuAGcAYQByAGQALgBjAG8AcgBwAAUAGABzAHUAbgBnAGEAcgBkAC4AYwBvAHIAcAAHAAgAcg4PLuVF1AEAAAAA'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No credentials are available in the security package\r\n   at System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(Byte[] incomingBlob, Boolean throwOnError, SecurityStatus& statusCode)\r\n   at System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(String incomingBlob)\r\n   at System.Net.NtlmClient.DoAuthenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate)\r\n   at System.Net.NtlmClient.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials)\r\n   at System.Net.AuthenticationManagerDefault.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials)\r\n   at System.Net.AuthenticationState.AttemptAuthenticate(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, ICredentials authInfo)\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmitForAuth()\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmit(Exception& e, Boolean& disableUpload)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest

Comment: I have exactly the same error, can anyone please show some pointers to a working solution?